# Upgrading existing code to DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a good chunk of the function complete.  I am just missing how to duplicate what I have done for a single block to a multiple check box block.

Here is what I have so far:

```
jQuery('#blockID, .msg_block').live('click', function () {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
        var blockList = [];
        var count = 0;
        jQuery('td input:checked').each(function () {
            count = count + 1;
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            blockList.push(tr.attr('replytoid'));
        });
        if (count >= 1) {
            blockDistID(blockList.join(', '), count, oTable, nTr);
        } else {
            //console.log(aData[4]);
            //console.log(jQuery('#replytoid').val());
            blockDistID(aData[4], 1, oTable, nTr);
            return false;
        }

    });
```

For this section in the above code:

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
blockList.push(tr.attr('replytoid'));
```

Is it possible for me to pull the data from the `oTable` object or `nTr`?

Previously I had attached this value into the id attribute section, but I am trying to now pull this data from the row itself.

I don't know if I need to separate these two functions out. `#blockID` is a button that should throw all of the ids into an array that are checked.

`.msg_block` is a button that blocks a single user.

This part of the code:

```
jQuery('td input:checked').each(function () {
            count = count + 1;
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            blockList.push(tr.attr('replytoid'));
        });
```

Needs to somehow grab the data for the row that `<td>` is checked.  All of the code needed is present to my knowledge, I am just not sure how to assign `aData` inside the above `input:checked` portion of code which will allow me to grab `aData[4]` and push that data into the array.

Comment: Comment rather than an answer because my brain is addled, but is there not a way you could put your logic into the fnRowCallback callback function in DataTables, rather than running it as a .each() on the constructed DOM? At the end of the day, it IS a "for each row" loop.

Comment: @GregPettit I'm sure there is a way, but I am unsure of how to accomplish that at the moment.  Currently I ran into a bug which is making me separate the two above click events into separate functions anyway.  It was producing bad results when check boxes were checked and you clicked the block this single person button. =(